# PHP Code Igniter : Session is not working in www.example.com but working in www.example.com/beta

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, ssl, subdomain

My site https://www.example.com is hosted in AWS EC2. I have test environment in www.example.com/beta. After the migration to www.example.com its worked fine initially. All of sudden the sessions are not working in www.example.com. But its working in www.example.com/beta. Only session id is generating, session values are not available after login.

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1578821066 )
```

I am having the following code to set the session during login,

```
$this->session->set_userdata('frontusername',$res->Email);
$this->session->set_userdata('frontname',$res->FirstName);
$this->session->set_userdata('frontuserid',$res->Id);
```

After login, while redirecting to dashboard, there is no variables in www.example.com

Both shares the same session variables.

```
session.save_path is /var/lib/php/sessions.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know how you think anyone will be able to tell you an answer to this, as you really don't provide any code or information. What did you change? would be a good question to help you get started

Comment: @Mikkel,  Have updated it. But there is no specific code to pinpoint the issue.